# getting fixed height div to continue on next line

Tags: html, css

Not at all sure that this is possible but on the off-chance, here is what I need:

- 100px high div with top and bottom border.
- an unknown number of items within the div that are displayed horizontally within the top and bottom borders of the parent div.
- Importantly, if more items are contained within the div that can fit horizontally, the div should continue with a new row of items below. This second row should also have the items displayed horizontally between the top and bottom borders of the parent div. I do not want the div to simply grow in height and start a new line because this will not allow the top and bottom borders to appear above and below each row of items.

[image]

Comment: I need a picture. Can you make a MSPaint scribble or something? If you add stuff to the div, it will have to grow in height.

Comment: is it vertical or horizontal  ?

Comment: use: `float:left;` for your boxes. Otherwise use ECMAscript

Comment: added picture for clarification

Comment: @roko - yes, that will allow the boxes to appear horizontally but the real problem is getting the parent div to continue and create a new row

Comment: As I said, *'than you'll have to use Javascript'*

Comment: what about something like `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the width of wrapper and put those blocks which are 100px high inside it.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/BVm5h/

Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="myClass">1</div>
 <div class="myClass">2</div>
 <div class="myClass">3</div>
 <div class="myClass">4</div>
 <div class="myClass">5</div>
 <div class="myClass">6</div>
 <div class="myClass">7</div>
 <div class="myClass">8</div>
 <div class="myClass">9</div>
 <div class="myClass">10</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {width: 600px;}

.myClass {
 border-top: 1px solid #FF0000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

div.myClass:last-child {
 width: 100%;
}​
```

JS:

```
var no = $('div.myClass').length;
var wlength = $('div.wrapper').width();
var length = $('div.myClass').width();
var tno = no*length;
while(wlength < tno)
 tno=tno-wlength;
var mw = wlength+length-tno;
$('div.myClass').last().css('max-width',mw);
```

​
​
By changing the width of wrapper, you can set the number of div blocks you wish in each row.

Edit: Added JS if the last element is to be extended for entire row.
​

Comment: Thanks very much. My only problem with this approach is that if you take off the last item (10), you can see that the borders do not go all the way across the page as they would if the wrapper had the border CSS. Any way around this?

Comment: @TheFlowerGuy That's why I said: use JS ;) 
 Ankit: +1 for the effort

Comment: @TheFlowerGuy: Edited the code so that last element now extends for the entire row. Also made the code more dynamic, which allows to change wrapper width and div block width.

Comment: @Roko : Yes to entend the border for the entire row, we do require JS :)

Answer (score 1):

Harnessing the power of background images.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/UTtVJ/1/

Edit: I noticed that the `#bottom-line` element didn't show up in ie7. Seemed to work +ie8. Probably easy to fix though. Since this solution is not so popular, I will not do anything about that..

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    background: url('http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/5188/linedu.png') repeat top left;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#inner-wrap {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
}

#wrap #top-line,
#wrap #bottom-line {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    background: url('http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/5188/linedu.png') repeat-x 0px -116px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#wrap #top-line { top: -8px; }
#wrap #bottom-line { bottom: -28px; }

#inner-wrap > div {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left:10px;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #111;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888;
}


​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top-line"></div>
    <div id="bottom-line"></div>
    <div id="inner-wrap">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
  </div>  
</div>​
```