# Div matrix structure using css

Tags: html, css

I am this html for my products display page in e-commerce site,  but some issues with alignment.... In this page will come near by 100 product  so i need to show it like matrix

```
<div  style=" margin: 0 auto; width:640px; text-align: left">
     <div class="leftcol" >left column 1
           <p>my text</p>
           <p>my text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="leftcol" >right column
           <p>my textmy text my text my text</p>
     </div>   
     <div class="leftcol" >left column
           <p>my text</p>
           <p>my text</p>
           <p>my text</p>
           <p>my text</p>
           <p>my text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="leftcol" >right column
          <p>my textmy text my text my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="leftcol" >
           left column 2
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
          <p>my text</p>
    </div>
```

My css

```
.leftcol{width: 200px;background:yellow;margin-right:10px;float:left; }
```

all product divs are in same size that `200px`, but the height of the div will change as like example, i need to show divs [like this](http://pinterest.com/) http://pinterest.com/

Display comes like this

[image]

[but i need to fill that gaps by next divs example see this site [http://pinterest.com/][1] http://pinterest.com/](http://pinterest.com/)

Comment: use http://masonry.desandro.com/ or http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: the shown gap is due to the content availability if you put the same amount of content on all div's they will look similar else put a height to all div so this will look same

Comment: :) for this can't add same amount of content to all product... because that height depend on product description... so it may vary

Comment: Why do you not just use an html table instead of css divs

Comment: you can use min height which wont mean exact height for all div

Comment: minimum height also makes empty space like above.. because less content divs makes empty space at bottom

Comment: @PhilipBevan what this answer... this issue begin in table only.. i tried to avoid with divs here... because this with tables impossible

Comment: till now the only idea is [link](http://masonry.desandro.com/)... but i searching for better then this, without any plugins

Comment: i do not think you can do this with purely css. maybe wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally div content from database cant align matrix with using only CSS. So surly we want use jQuery i go with "@Gaby aka G. Petrioli" answer in comment

use [masonry.desandro.com](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope.metafizzy.co](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 1):

Almost similar to [getting fixed height div to continue on next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278299/getting-fixed-height-div-to-continue-on-next-line/10278584#10278584).

For your requirement, this should match: http://jsfiddle.net/bXvaj/

Answer (score 1):

Both masonry and pinterest uses absolute positioning to achieve what you need. And I'm guessing that it is a must for complex layouts where you have responsiveness as well.

But for a simple fixed-width one, I would probably do this:

```
<ul id="matte">
   <ul id="first-col">

      <ul class="product-cat">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         ...
      </ul>

      <ul class="product-cat">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         ...
      </ul>

   </ul>

   <ul id="second-col">

      <ul class="product-cat">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         ...
      </ul>

      <ul class="product-cat">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         ...
      </ul>

   </ul>


   <ul id="third-col">

      <ul class="product-cat">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         ...
      </ul>

      <ul class="product-cat">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         ...
      </ul>

   </ul>
</ul>
```

So, the idea behind this is to divide the layout into columns and add content based on the shortest one, rather than calculating the whole layout in js. This can even be used with user-generated content I guess where you detect the shortest and inject content accordingly

Comment: All div's are loading dynamically from database, so all div's created in loop cant use separate UL like this...

Comment: Why not? I used ul's for being semantic but you can replace them with divs. ul class="product-cat" would be the equivalent of your div class="leftcol" 

That would mean that you only need 3 extra divs/ul's for the columns to implement this and a small snipplet to detect and add content to the shortest column.

Comment: can you please give any reference page link? @Ege

Comment: @Dhamu it was a bit tricky but I managed to to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/T8ka5/1/

Comment: @Dhamu Ok so just noticed that it won't work when all of them are empty, or has the same height, but a few tweaks on the code should make it work.

Comment: Updated the code to work when any of them is empty. http://jsfiddle.net/T8ka5/4/ Now only one scenario remains where any of the columns have the equal height. It would work but for both of them.

Comment: But ege what i need means, all div's are automatically **fetched from database**, so **can't use by columns** i must need all block individual but with matrix alignment... **all like by example picture above in question**